# How to handle Linq to Entity exceptions (errors)?

Tags: linq-to-entities

What is the best way to handle linq to entity exceptions? Can I use try and catch block or is there better way?

Answer (score 0):

We used a try block to shield us from Save errors.

```
try{
  using(Context context = new Context()){
     Entity x = context.Entities.First();
     x.ModifyMe = true;
     context.SaveChanges();
   }
 }catch(UpdateException e){
  //convert to friendly message
 }
```

If you want to catch a lower exception there is also a OptimisticConcurrencyException

We also took it a bit further and just wrapped our SaveChanges in an extension method that was called protected save changes.

```
public static class Extension{
  public static List<Error> ProtectedSaveChanges(this ObjectContext context){
      try{
        context.SaveChanges();

      }catch(UpdateException e ){
          //Convert to freindly and return
      }
  }

}
```

And believe it or not we decided to take it even further and have a special function that defined how to convert the exception method to a more user friendly error.  If you want that one as well let me know and I can post.

As for an alternative way, i have seen people use exception shielding (EL), but i do not know if any built in Event Handlers for errors.